# IF AND conditional formatting not working - Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

Okay so I’m trying to format cells that are blank and meet the logical test. Here’s the formula:

```
=IF(AND($B2="Y", ISBLANK($C$2:$F$172)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

If both tests are true (B column = Y and there are blanks in the range), I want those cells to be formatted yellow.

So far, I’ve been using the “Edit formatting rule” under the “Manage Rules” window. It accepts the formula, but it either formats *all* blanks yellow, regardless of the B column, or doesn’t format any blanks at all.

Comment: Are you trying to format the blanks in the range `C2:F172`? If that's the case, you shouldn't reference the entire range. Rather, you should use a relative reference. `=AND($B2="Y", ISBLANK(C2))`

Answer (score 1):

You only need the condition to reference cells for one row, I.e

If "applies to" range is C2:F172 Then make the formula apply to the first cell, like this

> =AND($B2="y",ISBLANK(C2))

The formula implicitly adjusts for each cell in the range

That will format all blank cells in rows where B column is "y".....or do you want all cells in a row formatted if **any** are blank in that row?